# Do i need to Submit Separate (Mobile) Sitemap for AMP pages?

Tags: seo, sitemap, google-search-console, amp-html, bing-webmaster-tools

before responsive design we need mobile specific sitemaps, but with responsive design they were not needed.

But with introduction of **Accelerate Mobile Pages (AMP)**, we are again having mobile specific URLs, so my questions are:

1. Do we need Separate (*Mobile*) Sitemap for AMP pages?
2. if yes, then what *schemas* we should use?
3. old schema http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-mobile/1.0? or something new?

Comment: Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on StackOverflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on the network site Pro Webmasters at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No need providing you have a `rel="amphtml"` link in your regular page to tell crawlers the AMP HTML version as discussed here:
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/discovery.html

Similarly your AMP pages should have a rel="canonical" link to point to real page, to avoid search engines thinking you have duplicate content.

In fact for Google, in the Google Search Console for you site there is an AMP section (under Search Appearance section) that shows all AMP pages it has found and if there are any problems with them.

Answer (score 1):

As BazzaDP said their no need for separate sitemap.But you need to add `rel="amphtml"` to the top of the page. But it is good to have separate site map for AMP page, the major reason is Google crawler will learn how your site interacts having a separate sitemap for amp will make it easy for Google Crawler to detect and display in search result though it is not necessary. My opinion if making sitemap for amp page is difficult for your stack leave it, If it not do it. As this will allow other search engine to detect easily. Creating separate sitemap doesn't give you any advantage.

As for your question, there is no need for it.